# How can I remove Google Chrome as default browser and switch back to Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, web-browser

Somehow my computer got a virus on it. It seems Google installed something called Chrome.app on my computer. Instead of Safari opening links, Chrome now does it. How can I remove this virus and restore order?

Comment: Google Chrome is a very legitimate web browser made by Google. It is, in fact, the most-used browser in the world, and many, many smart people use it. It's not a virus (in fact you probably should be using it) and it's definitely not "hijacking your searches". You can certainly change your default browser back to Safari as RedEagle mentioned, and even delete Chrome if you don't want to have it. Rest assured, your computer was not "infected" by Google. If you don't believe us, you can download a trustworthy antivirus app like Avast or BitDefender and run a scan.

Comment: Might want to research about Google Chrome a bit more. Take a look at [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome).

Answer (score 3):

Open Safari, then click "Safari" in the bar up top, then in the dropdown menu, click "Preferences". There, you should find where you can change your default browser back to Safari.

To get rid of Chrome afterwards, open your `Applications` folder in Finder and move the Chrome app into the trash.

Comment: How do I stop it from hijacking my searches though?

Comment: @chromaticsyllabus What do you mean?

Comment: Please don't use comments for follow-up questions, post a new question instead (and add a link to the question above if context is required).

Comment: Don't forget to empty your trash afterwards so Chrome doesn't hang around in your trash can.